# LINQ vs nested loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The code Im maintaining has a common pattern like the following, a nested loop with an if to find certain elements.

```
        foreach (Storage storage in mStorage.Values)
            foreach (OrderStorage oStorage in storage.OrderStorage)
                if (oStorage.OrderStorageId == orderStorageId)
```

I was thinking to change this into LINQ:

```
        foreach (OrderStorage oStorage in (from storage in mStorage.Values
                                           from oStorage in storage.OrderStorage
                                           where oStorage.OrderStorageId == orderStorageId
                                           select oStorage))
```

But it doesnt seem all that appealing because it's less transparent whats going on here, more objects may be created costing performance in terms of both memory and cpu. Will there actually be more objects created or does the C# compiler emit code resembling the nested loop with an if inside?

Comment: [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses**.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Will there actually be more objects created or does the C# compiler emit code resembling the nested loop with an if inside?

More objects; each LINQ operation (`SelectMany`, `Where`, `Select` etc) will result in a new place-holder object that represents the pending `IEnumerable<T>` query of that operation, and then when it is finally iterated, each of those will result in an enumerator instance, along with the context etc. Plus there is a captured-variable context for the hoisted `orderStorageId`, etc.

Note that the regular `foreach` will also result in an enumerator instance, but `foreach` has the advantage that it can also use duck-typed enumerators - which means that for things like `List<T>` it is actually using a `struct` enumerator, not a `class` enumerator. And of course using the local variable (`orderStorageId`) directly (rather than in an anonymous method) means that it doesn't need to be hoisted into a state/context object.

So yes, the raw `foreach` is more direct and efficient. The interesting question is: is the difference *important*. Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Agree with @marcgravell that there is a perf hit with LINQ, but it allows for potential increased maintainability and potentially easier parallelism. The perf vs maintainability dilemma is what makes computer programming an art.